# Exporting data from own telegram account with the help of a bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, scrape, php-telegram-bot

This is my first post on the platform. There is a task that I want to achieve and I need advises regarding how to achieve it.

My telegram account has thousands of chats with thousands of people that I talked over time. However none of these people are “added as a contact”. But the conversations are there.

I need a windows or MacOs bot which can navigate through my personal chats and private telegram groups to export the telegram handle of the person that I ever connected, talked.

I have simply development skills, I would appreciate if anyone with an experience guided me through this task.

I believe a Pyhton bot would be the right thing to do, but what else it could be an option? A bot that can control my mouse to navigate through my chats and copy everything I need one by one would be another options but I am not sure how can I achieve this.

I am open to all type of advises.
Thanks

Native export option from telegram doesn’t work, and I don’t really give access to my telegram to a third party paid bot.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe a Pythton bot would be the right thing to do

Nope, a (python) Telegram bot can't access your private chats so that won't help.

---

The only way to achieve this is by creating [your own Telegram app](https://core.telegram.org/api#tdlib--build-your-own-telegram) using the [TDLib Library](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started).

Since you've tagged this with [python](/questions/tagged/python), I'd suggest taking a look at [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/).

Telethon allows you to create your own Telegram client that can loop over all your chats using (eg) [`iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs). Then you can extract the needed data from that chat and use it to your liking.